# Python package for discrete preferences

Tags: software, python, discrete-preferences

Do you know of a package allowing to create objects representing agents with (strict) preferences over (a finite set of) discrete objects $A,B,C,…$, and profiles thereof.

A minimal requirement would be to have  a method like `compare` defined on any instance `agent` of the class, with `agent.compare(X,Y)` returning `True` if the agent likes $X$ more than $Y$, and `False` otherwise.

The only related package I have found so far is [`svvamp`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svvamp). Do you know of any other?